# How to Disable edit button in Child Records

Tags: button

[image]

i wanted to delete Edit button in the childs.How can i Achieve this,!?Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot "directly" remove these buttons, as they are related to the user's permissions and generated dynamically. If you remove the `Cluster Field Configurations: Edit" permission from the user's profile, they will no longer be able to see the Edit link or button anywhere. Alternatively, you can also adjust your organization-wide defaults to prevent users from editing records they should not.

Comment: my Custom Object "Cluster Field Configaration is not showing in org wide settings"

Comment: @Satya It's a profile setting, not sharing.

Comment: iam using admin Profile

Comment: iam not able to do in Admin profile,that is why i had choosen org widedefaults

Comment: @Satya Admins can edit whatever they want. Simply removing the link doesn't change anything. There's no way to effectively restrict admins from doing whatever they like.

Answer (score 0):

You can click on the "Edit layout" button on the top of the page.

Then, drag the "Edit" button from its position to the header to remove it.

Comment: i did like this,but button will be disabled from Detailed view.But not the related lists.